# Android: How do I get file's last modification date?

Tags: android

The application need write file's last modification date.

```
 void Dater(String DateFile) {
          File file = new File(DateFile);
          if(file.exists()){
              Long lastModified = file.lastModified();
              Date date = new Date(lastModified);
              textView2.setText(String.valueOf(date));
          }
      }
```

But textView2 is empty. 
The file is ok (I open it).

```
Dater("n" + String.valueOf(itemname)+".txt");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your file.exists() fails. Give the absolute path of the file

If internal file then

```
Dater(activity.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/n" + String.valueOf(itemname)+".txt");
```

If on the sdcard then

```
Dater(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/n" + String.valueOf(itemname)+".txt");
```